# TC Bandwidth throttle script error

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I'm currently using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  tc uses the following units when passed as a parameter.
#  kbps: Kilobytes per second
#  mbps: Megabytes per second
#  kbit: Kilobits per second
#  mbit: Megabits per second
#  bps: Bytes per second
#       Amounts of data can be specified in:
#       kb or k: Kilobytes
#       mb or m: Megabytes
#       mbit: Megabits
#       kbit: Kilobits
#  To get the byte figure from bits, divide the number by 8 bit
#

#
# Name of the traffic control command.
TC=/sbin/tc

# The network interface we're planning on limiting bandwidth.
IF=eth0             # Interface

# Download limit (in mega bits)
DNLD=1mbit          # DOWNLOAD Limit

# Upload limit (in mega bits)
UPLD=1mbit          # UPLOAD Limit

# IP address of the machine we are controlling
IP=216.3.128.12     # Host IP

# Filter options for limiting the intended interface.
U32="$TC filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32"

start() {

# We'll use Hierarchical Token Bucket (HTB) to shape bandwidth.
# For detailed configuration options, please consult Linux man
# page.

$TC qdisc add dev $IF root handle 1: htb default 30
$TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $DNLD
$TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate $UPLD
$U32 match ip dst $IP/32 flowid 1:1
$U32 match ip src $IP/32 flowid 1:2

# The first line creates the root qdisc, and the next two lines
# create two child qdisc that are to be used to shape download
# and upload bandwidth.
#
# The 4th and 5th line creates the filter to match the interface.
# The 'dst' IP address is used to limit download speed, and the
# 'src' IP address is used to limit upload speed.

}

stop() {

# Stop the bandwidth shaping.
$TC qdisc del dev $IF root

}

restart() {

# Self-explanatory.
stop
sleep 1
start

}

show() {

# Display status of traffic control status.
$TC -s qdisc ls dev $IF

}

case "$1" in

start)

echo -n "Starting bandwidth shaping: "
start
echo "done"
;;

stop)

echo -n "Stopping bandwidth shaping: "
stop
echo "done"
;;

restart)

echo -n "Restarting bandwidth shaping: "
restart
echo "done"
;;

show)

echo "Bandwidth shaping status for $IF:"
show
echo ""
;;

*)

pwd=$(pwd)
echo "Usage: tc.bash {start|stop|restart|show}"
;;

esac exit 0
```

Which can be found at:
http://atmail.com/kb/2009/throttling-bandwidth/

However running the default script or my properlly configured one returns this error:

```
[root@A20S27 ~]# /etc/init.d/shaping start
/etc/init.d/shaping: line 117: syntax error near unexpected token `exit'
/etc/init.d/shaping: line 117: `esac exit'
```

I've attempted looking around online but wasn't able to find much out about this line. Has anyone got any information into what could be causing  this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the code might not be formatted correctly.

Try putting exit 0 on a new line like so:

```
pwd=$(pwd)
echo "Usage: tc.bash {start|stop|restart|show}"
;;

esac 

exit 0
```

esac is used to close out case statements in bash.

Hope that helps!